# Evaluate the limit of $\ \tan \frac{\pi \sqrt{3x-11}}{x-5}$ as $x\to 5$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x)= \lim_{x \to 5} \left[5  \tan\left( \frac{\pi \sqrt{3x-11}}{x-5} \right)\right]$$

I'm not sure on how to approach this.

Am I allowed to plug $x=5$ in the numerator and end up with $\tan(2\pi)$?

Comment: The answer when I plug in f(5) to it is 3pi/4. Does anyone know how to get that?

Comment: It does not make sense to have $f(x)$ on the left. The limit is a number, or infinity, or does not exist at all -- but it is not a function of $x$. On the right side, $x$ is a dummy variable.

Answer (score 4):

No, as then you would be dividing by 0. I think you're supposed to use l'Hopital's rule here.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, if $f(c)=g(c)=0 \text{ or } \pm \infty, $

Comment: How does that help here?

Comment: @ChantryCargill The question was originally worded as $5\lim_{x \rightarrow 5}\frac{\tan (\pi \sqrt{3x-11})}{x-5}$, (without Latex) until it was edited to its current form.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule can be used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking,

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on $D$  and $x_0 \in D$, then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

However, 5 is not in the domain of $\tan\frac{\pi \sqrt{3x-11)}}{x-5}$, so you can not plug 5 in the  numerator.